# How can I make a drawer pre-load information from the Firebase database in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a drawer in my App and I need to make it display some info about the current user. I did it, but the data I need only show up after a few seconds because the functions to get it are inside the widget.
Here's some code:

```
class MainDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainDrawerState createState() => _MainDrawerState();
}

class _MainDrawerState extends State<MainDrawer> {
  UserCore user = UserCore();
  Future getUser() async {
    var uid = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((val) {
      return val.uid;
    });

    Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((val) {
      user = UserCore.fromMap(val.documents[0]);
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(59, 46, 46, 1),
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          //padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "img/logo.png",
                    width: 100,
                  ),
                ),
                drawerInfo("User: ", user.info1 == "" ? user.info2: user.info1),
                drawerInfo("Email: ", user.email),
              ],
            ),
```

This is the core part of the code and my final question is, how can I make the data comming from the Firebase database stop of suddenly popping in the drawer and be already there when the user open it?
This drawer are present in most of the app, so passing the info as a parameter are impracticable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading data from Firebase, which means it may have to come from the network, and that will inevitably take time. There are many ways to  make this (seem) faster to the user though:

1. Use a faster network connection, or move closer to the server. While I know these are often not realistic, it is important to set your expectation right: the majority of the time your user is waiting is of three factors:

   1. Their distance to the servers that contain the data, typically translated into latency: the time it takes to send a data packet to the server and get a response back.
   2. The available bandwidth of their connection, as that determines how fast data can be sent from/to their device.
   3. The amount of data that your code is requesting, since sending/receiving more data will take longer.

   As the first two options are unlikely under your control, the only one of these that you **can** control is the amount of data that you request. Be sure to only request data that you absolutely need to display. You seem to be doing so already, but it **is** usually something to consider.
2. Cache the data locally, and reload it from there. Firestore automatically stores any data it receives in a disk cache on the local device, and can load it from there when the app requests it again. But the way you are currently loading the user document bypasses that cache, and forces the request to be answered from the server.

   There are two ways to fix this:

   1. Force the [`getDocuments()` call](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html) to come from the cache, by passing `Source: Source.serverAndCache` into it. If you get a result there, show it to the user. If you don't get a result, you'll still have to request it from the server.
   2. Use a [realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), which first returns the document(s) from the cache, then checks with the server for updates, and calls your code again with any updates. This means the user sees the locally cached version right away, and then **may** see an update after a few moments.

Comment: I used the `source: Source.serverAndCache`, but seems like the app is trying to get the data from the server first. How can I use a Realtime Listener to fix this? Sorry for this bunch of questions, I'm still learning back-end.

Comment: That's why I said you should use two separate `getDocuments()` calls or a realtime listener. The realtime listener pretty much does a `cacheFirstAndThenServer` type operation.